# AWS ELB zero downtime deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-deployment, elastic-load-balancer

With an ELB setup, there as healthcheck timeout, e.g. take a server out of the LB if it fails X fail checks.

For a real zero down time deployment, I actually want to be able to avoid these extra 4-5 seconds of down time.

Is there a simple way to do that on the ops side, or does this needs to be in the level of the web server itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're doing continuous deployment you should deregister the instance you're deploying to from ELB (say, `aws elb deregister-instances-from-load-balancer`), wait for the current connections to drain, deploy you app and then register an instance with ELB.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elb/deregister-instances-from-load-balancer.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elb/register-instances-with-load-balancer.html

It is also a common strategy to deploy to another AutoScaling Group, then just switch ASG on the load balancer.

Comment: Thanks. I saw this one - https://github.com/opbeat/elb-dance - seems to makes this easier. My problem with this approach is that it really adds a complexity to the deployment flow. but if no other option comes up, i'll take this direction.

Comment: It should be complex 'cause it's very customizable. For easy deployments there is AWS Beanstalk.

Comment: Worth noting that even with register/deregister, still seeing none 2xx responses over load. :(